# Hbase - Importtsv - how to not import empty fields

Tags: csv, import, hbase, nosql

I use importtsv to import data in Hbase.

In my tsv files, some fields are empty. How can I do to not import them in Hbase ?

For example, I have a table called Test in Hbase. My tsv file called test.tsv looks like :

```
1   a   b   c   d
2   q       f   s
```

When I do :

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv  -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,I:c1,I:c2,I:c3,I:c4 Test test.tsv
```

I have these results :

```
 1  column=I:c1, timestamp=1400855636910, value=a
 1  column=I:c2, timestamp=1400855636910, value=b
 1  column=I:c3, timestamp=1400855636910, value=c
 1  column=I:c4, timestamp=1400855636910, value=d
 2  column=I:c1, timestamp=1400855636910, value=q
 2  column=I:c2, timestamp=1400855636910, value=
 2  column=I:c3, timestamp=1400855636910, value=f
 2  column=I:c4, timestamp=1400855636910, value=s
```

Even if the second field is empty in line 2 of my tsv file, a record is create on Hbase.
How can I avoid that?

Comment: any luck with this ?

Comment: any luck on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a custom MapReduce job:  https://github.com/jrkinley/hbase-bulk-import-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudera/examples/hbase/bulkimport/HBaseKVMapper.java

Answer (score 0):

add -Dimporttsv.skip.empty.columns=true